# My first Neural Network not working

Tags: neural-network, keras, tensorflow

I have just started deep learning and neural networks and when I try the following code, it does not work:

```
#Import Keras for deep learning
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
#Store the data into a variable
data = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist
#Split the data and create classes
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = data.load_data()
class_names = ['T-shirt/top', 'Trouser', 'Pullover', 'Dress', 'Coat', 'Sandal', 'Shirt', 'Sneaker', 'Bag', 'Ankle boot']
#Standardize the data
train_images = train_images/255
test_images = test_images/255
#Create the model
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28,28))
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation = 'relu')
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation = 'softmax')
])
#Compile and fit the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=5)
#Test the model
test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(test_images, test_labels)
print(test_acc)
```

For some reason this is not working.This is the error:

```
 File "<ipython-input-6-90a7b393ff3f>", line 15
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation = 'relu')
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Check this https://keras.io/guides/sequential_model/, no keras.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed a comma at the end of line 15, replace the part with this code:

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28,28)), # comma here
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation = 'relu'), # comma here
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation = 'softmax')
])
```

Then it works

Comment: Thanks a lot, knew it was something easy!